# exception Nuget MvcScaffolding

Tags: nuget-package

Exception calling "EnumerateFiles" with "3" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."
At E:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ArtsProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.9\tools\init.ps1:35 char:8
+         | %{ [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($_, "*." + $extension, [System.IO.S ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: There is the same bug related discussion at CodePlex — https://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/discussions/392089